# MS thesis defense equivalent to publishing as a MS student?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, thesis-committee

When applying to Ph.D. at the top 10 programs in the US, does MS thesis defended to committee members have the same weight as publishing paper as a MS student? Or am I at the disadvantage of not having any publications?

I was in EE working in Physics department in the field of Quantum Optics.

Comment: Of course it's literally not "a publication", but a M.S. thesis rather than coursework-only M.S. has some advantage. In math, it might also have a disadvantage of thinner coursework preparation. What is your situation?

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I took 6 courses/ 20 credits in the area of specialization. MS research done under the supervision of PI in the field of quantum optics, had some interesting results. Main disadvantage I had was that it was completely new topic in the lab and no other student was working along with me.

Comment: For physics of any sort, I do not have enough experience to offer any useful opinion about this question... I _suspect_ (with slim evidence) that there is a bit of math-like expectations of coursework, more so than (apparently) computer science. But someone else will hopefully give a real answer. Also, my remarks about math apply only to the U.S. system, essentially, wherein undergrad course prep is usually thinner than elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a defense is not equivalent to a publication. A defense may just be something required by university rules and takes some of the responsibility and guidance from the advisor and gives it to others. Some such theses are available in, say, the university library, but that isn't the same as journal (or conference) publication which is more *public* by definition.

The defense is usually a closed system within a department, thought there could be external members of the committee. But a publication has been vetted by independent referees and an editor and it is done in competition with other papers.

And if a defense is required there is no reason that you can't also do a paper if the results are good. It might not be the thesis itself, but could be based on the work.

A publication is almost certainly better if you plan a career as an academic, but possibly not by a tremendous amount. The admissions committee may actually do some (probably minor) evaluation of the work in either case. But having a publication in a reputable place will relieve them of some of the burden of judgement.